# Laravel form macro in test

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I crated a file macros.php next to routes.php

```
Form::macro("check", function($name, $value = 1, $checked = null, $options = array()){
    return Form::hidden($name, 0).Form::checkbox($name, $value, $checked, $options);
});
```

And I load it in the start/global.php with:

```
require_once app_path().'/macros.php';
```

Everything works fine in views but when I try to unittest a view with that macro, I get the following error

```
Caused by
BadMethodCallException: Method check does not exist.
```

Does anybody know why does this fail?
Thank you so much!

Comment: how are you doing the unit testing ? are you using mockery ? can you give us some code ?